# PHP: Performance PLIST/XML vs. MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, plist

I wantet to ask about the performance of MySQL vs. PLIST (apple XML standard).

I'm realising a localization class for my website. Now, I have two possible variants:

-a file localization.plist, where some labels and texts of the website gets saved, as follows:

```
<dict>
    <key>testmessage</key>
    <dict>
        <key>en</key>
        <string>Test-message-string</string>
        <key>de</key>
        <string>Test-Nachricht</string>
        <key>fr</key>
        <string>C'est une teste</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then, there is the alternative with using MySQL and selecting labels from a database, as follows:

```
SELECT LABEL FROM LABELS WHERE ID = $id AND LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en';
```

Now, which one would be better with its performance? MySQL has a connection to establish, which may be a bit a long time, and plist is quite more complex...

Thanks for your inputs :)

Regs, flo

Comment: I would benchmark it, but my gut feeling is any file-include approach will beat running a mysql query for every page request. Maybe store all of your keys/values in a database for organization and then only run a query periodically to generate p-list files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i wouldnt use either.. if you want to use something with human readable XML based storage then use `XLIFF` or `TMX`. If it doesnt need to be human readable then use `gettext`.

Also typically you have a file for every language and your `key` is the phrase in the source language, and your value is the translate phrase to the language of the file in question.